# Why we use `Box::pin` for !Unpin and `Pin::new` for Unpin?

Tags: rust

I get confused when learning implementation of Pin in rust.

I understand when a type is not safe to move, it can impl `!Unpin`. `Pin` is to prevent others get `&mut T` from these types, so that they can not be `std::mem::swap`.

If Pin is designed for `!Unpin` types, why we can't just call `Pin::new` on those types?

It gives error like the following. I know I should use Pin::new_unchecked, but why?

```
struct TestNUnpin {
    b: String,
}
impl !Unpin for TestNUnpin {}

// error: the trait `Unpin` is not implemented for `TestNUnpin`
std::pin::Pin::new(&TestNUnpin{b: "b".to_owned()});
```

My reasoning is:

1. Pin is to help !Unpin types
2. We can pass !Unpin types to Pin::new to make them unmovable.
3. For Unpin types, they can not be pinned, so we can't created by Pin::new

Comment: impl `!Unpin` is *not* the same as `impl Unpin`.   Why are you using the negative trait?  Remove the `!` and it will work.

Comment: @AhmedMasud I know they are not the same, in fact contradict. I can use PhantomPinned, it doesn't change my question. And my question is not why this does not work, but why this is **designed** to do so.

Comment: Aaah... Well essentially the compiler needs a way to annotate that the Box will not Unpin the pointer, and leave it in place.  However there is no way for Box::pin to annotate it by itself and the !Unpin ensures that contract is maintained inside an `unsafe` block by the developer.  (I hope this isn't confusing) As an addition, if you DO implement Unpin then Box will unpin it.  Now think of an API which assumes `!Unpin` and you create a wrapper that Does impl Unpin and box that. There would be trouble ...

Comment: `struct A; struct B { a: A }` and A needs to be pinned to function. But you impl `Unpin` for B and now things go bad. However if you annotate A with `!Unpin` then things work alright.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think what you're looking for can be found in the [Safety section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/pin/struct.Pin.html#safety) of `Pin::new_unchecked`. Essentially, `Pin` should guarantee that the pinned value will *never* move again (unless it implements `Unpin`), even after the `Pin` is dropped. An example of this failing is `Pin<&mut T>`. You can drop the `Pin` and the value is no longer borrowed, so you're free to move it again, breaking `Pin`'s core guarantee. Here's an example:

```
use std::marker::PhantomPinned;
use std::pin::Pin;

fn main() {
    let x = PhantomPinned;
    
    {
        let _pin = Pin::new(&x); // error[E0277]: `PhantomPinned` cannot be unpinned
    }

    let y = Box::new(x); // the PhantomPinned is moved here!
}
```

This check simply isn't doable at compile-time without adding a whole lot of extra complexity to the borrow checker, so it's marked as `unsafe`, essentially saying it's the developer's job to make sure it works. The reason `Box::pin` exists and is safe is because the developers of `Box` can guarantee its safety: `Box` is an owned and unique pointer, so once its `Pin` is dropped, its value is also dropped, and there's no longer any way to move the value.

Comment: Can I understand this way? We can `Pin::new` an Unpin because Pin doesn't care if it will be moved. We can not directly `Pin::new` an `!Unpin` because Pin doesn't know if it will be moved. Since what Pin do is only protecting the pointer it holds from any operation that requires `&mut`, Pin won't check whether the pointer will be moved before or after Pin's lifetime, which needs to be guaranteed by us. Why `Box::pin` is safe for `!Unpin` is because Box is owned and unique, it won't live longer than Pin?

Comment: Yes. `Box::pin` creates a `Box` that has the same exact "lifetime" as its `Pin`.

Comment: @calvin *Why Box::pin is safe for !Unpin is because Box is owned and unique* - `Pin<Box<T>>` implements `Unpin` because because `Box` allocates the value on the heap, and that value doesn't move around in memory even if you move the variable that holds the `Pin<Box<T>>`. That's why `Pin<Box<T>>` is `Unpin` even if `T` is not `Unpin`.

Comment: @user4815162342 I think the important thing here is that the value in the `Box` can **only** be accessed through the `Pin`. In a `Pin<&mut T>`, you can move the `Pin` around all you want and it also won't move the value, but once the `Pin` goes away the value can be accessed and moved.

Comment: @Aplet123 I agree, and you covered that in the answer nicely. I was covering the other part, why `Box<T>` is move-safe to begin with, even if `T` isn't - because the box provides an almost immovable storage for `T`. ("Almost" because you can move `T` out of the box with `std::mem::replace()` - but `Pin<Box<T>>` fixes that hole by not giving out `&mut T` except in specially checked circumstances.)